# How to add roles to user after payment successfully?

Tags: 8, ubercart

I have use module ubercart to create product. I want user after payment successfully, user will be created, add add roles to user. How can i do that **with ui or custom module**?

I tested module rules but **I don't know how to check payment successfully**. With custom module, **I don't know check event can to add function to add roles**.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure what the right way is to check for a successful payment, but to actually set the role have you looked at the User::addRole method ( http://bit.ly/2kGXgK1)

Comment: perhaps related https://www.drupal.org/node/2803209

Comment: and https://www.drupal.org/node/2748827